# Is there mat-toolbar-column in Angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, toolbar

Is there mat-toolbar-column as like mat-toolbar-row? If not then how can I achieve below like layout in Angular material.
[expected material toolbar layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCLMo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Combine material-toolbar with flex-box like this:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <div class="container" fxFill>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxFill>
          <div fxFlex="75" fxLayour="row">
            <span>Logo</span>
          </div>
          <div fxFlex="25" fxLayour="column">
            <div fxLayout="row">
              <span>Carrear</span>
              <span>Contact US</span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>Home</span>
              <span>About US</span>
              <span>Products</span>
              <span>News</span>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know no (2021).

If you like to have a column, you have to create a mat-toolbar with defined width and add mat-toolbar-row for each row.